# I cannot make text white in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I am trying to make text white in a Google Sheets. I select the text, changed its color to white:

[image]

... and when I click in another cell or press Enter to validate, it goes back to the base color:

[image]

Although this is not blocking, it is certainly more readable to have white text in cells with a background color, so I would love to find how to do this...

In case this wasn't clear, what I am trying to do is to have complete control over the colors of the text used within cells - for example, having two (or more) colors cohabit in one cell, the way text editors "normally" function when dealing with text colors:

[image: screenshot of Apple Numbers]
(screenshot of Apple Numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the text
2. On the Google Sheets toolbar, click on the text color button
3. Click on white

[image]

**NOTE:** To be able to apply different colors different parts of the cell content, the value data type should be text. You could coerce the value data type as text by prepending a single quote/apostrophe  `'`

Example:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying it's not possible to have two different colors for text in the same cell?

Comment: The question doesn't ask about having two different colors on the text cell. Please update your question to clarify it.

Comment: I just edited it